# Django reverse url with parameters to a class based view

Tags: python, django, hyperlink, django-class-based-views

I just started learning python and django and I have a question.
I got the assignment to turn function views into class based views. But my links wont work now.

these are from urls.py:

```
url(r'^$', ContactIndex.as_view()),
url(r'^add$', ContactAdd.as_view()),
url(r'^([0-9]+)/update$', ContactUpdate.as_view()),
url(r'^([0-9]+)/view$', ContactView.as_view()),
```

This is my link :

```
{% url rtr_contact.views.ContactView contact.id %}
```

but this doesnt work it says:

```
Caught NoReverseMatch while rendering: Reverse for 'rtr_contact.views.ContactView' with arguments '(20L,)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.
```

Comment: You should suffix your url patterns with a slash. It's a standard in Django also it makes it easier for other programs to work with it (without going into gory details ...)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To make url reversing easy, I recommend that you always [name your url patterns](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#naming-url-patterns).

```
url(r'^$', ContactIndex.as_view(), name="contact_index"),
url(r'^add$', ContactAdd.as_view(), name="contact_add"),
url(r'^([0-9]+)/update$', ContactUpdate.as_view(), name="contact_update"),
url(r'^([0-9]+)/view$', ContactView.as_view(), name="contact_view"),
```

Then in the template:

```
{% url contact_view contact.id %}
```

Comment: Thank you, It worked. I wish the documentation of django was easier.

Comment: I think that on the whole, Django documentation is excellent. The section on class based views is a bit bare, but hopefully it will get fleshed out in future.

Comment: It's the future, and the class-based generic-views docs are still lacking. Thanks for your answer - it helped me out too.