# django 1.3 url template tag and class-based views

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates, django-class-based-views

I'm just starting to migrate an app I have to 1.3 from 1.1.

I'm starting to get in the thick of class based views and am blown away, but not really in a good way.
I have some gripes but the specific question here is:

**Is this the only way i can use the url template tag with a generic class-based view?**
[Django reverse url with parameters to a class based view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8588522/link-to-a-class-based-view)
**i.e. having to name every single url entry?**

It seems ridiculous to me as one of the fundamental philosophies of Django is DRY and yet here we are.... RY-ing.....

Thanks in advance.

**Edit:**
So I have https://gist.github.com/1877374

and get the error
TemplateSyntaxError
Caught NoReverseMatch while rendering: Reverse for 'views.HomeView.as_view' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.

Am I using this incorrectly?

---

**Tangent:**
I'd like to explain a little bit more about why I believe we are RY-ing if we have to name **every single entry** in the urls.py file

my urls.py typically looks like
https://gist.github.com/1877462

I understand completely about decoupling.
The point here is that we have the ability to do so **when required**. I absolutely use the name feature, when i need to. Otherwise, why would i want to spend the time and energy to redundently add url to every entry and name every entry when often they will be the same as the name of the class/funciton in views.py?

Maybe this should be branched into a seperate question on SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a rather hand-waving explanation of why you can't reverse the class based views without naming them. I'm not really familiar with the Django internals, so I'm happy to be corrected.

With a function based view,

```
# my_app.views.py
def my_view(request):
    return HttpResponse("Hello, world!")
```

you can reverse `my_app.views.my_view`, because it is the path of a callable view function.

With a class based view,

```
# my_app.views.py
class MyView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "hello_world.html"
```

you can't reverse `my_app.views.MyView`, because it isn't a callable view object. The callable view is `MyView.as_view()`. If you assigned `MyView.as_view()` to a variable in your views as follows:

```
# my_app.views.py
class MyView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "hello_world.html"
my_view = MyView.as_view()

# urls.py
url('^$', `my_view`),
```

then you *would* be able to reverse `my_view` without naming it. This option is just as much repeating as naming your url, so I don't think you'll like it!.

However when you put `MyView.as_view()` directly in your url pattern, it's an anonymous function. It hasn't been assigned to any variable, so there is no path you can use to reverse it. Similarly, you wouldn't be able to reverse the following:

```
url('^$', lambda request: HttpResponse("Hello, World!")),
```

Note that [`url()`](https://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/conf/urls/__init__.py) is basically just a function that makes it easier to add named url patterns. If you really don't want to name your urls, you could write your own function that automatically generates names for you.

Comment: Thanks for replying to this Alasdair. When I attempt to do {% url MyView.as_view %} shouldn't this work then? why does it need to be assigned as a variable in my view? I thought the view classes inherit the as_view() function which should make them callable?

Comment: `MyView.as_view` isn't a callable view. It's a method that returns a callable view. If you don't assign `MyView.as_view()` to a variable, it's an anonymous function, so cannot be reversed.

Comment: pre-django1.3 when we were working with function based views, why weren't the function views treated as anonymous functions (when we passed them in the url pattern)? I mean we were basically feeding the url function methods weren't we? they just happened to be what we defined as views. I'm not seeing the difference between calling the class-based MyView.as_view() vs. the function-based my_view()

Comment: I'm not sure whether you understand what anonymous functions are. I don't think I can explain my answer any better than I already have.

Comment: re-reading your answers and thinking it over again, I think I understand now. Thanks for your taking the time to articulate your explanation @Alasdair.

Comment: This is a really useful answer, explaining the internals. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Alasdair I came across a project that does what you show in the ex) views.py: my_view = MyView.as_view() everywhere, and imports my_view into urls.py and names it as well.  Is there any good reason that would have been done?

Comment: @phazei Importing the view would prevent duplication if a view is used in more than one url pattern. It also keeps the view logic in the  `views.py` instead of `urls.py`. I would always recommend naming urls patterns, even if they could technically be reversed using the function path. If you really want to know why the author of the project did it that way, you'd be better to ask him or her!

Comment: If only I could ask, it's an, ahem... adopted project with a load of 'customized' (non-standard django) modifications and someone decided: oh, this is a good place to start your first python/django site. I'm now our company's only django dev.

Answer (score 2):

First, this is not repeating yourself. Where are you naming the URL twice? That would be repeating yourself.

Second, naming of url patterns is not required - **but offers many advantages** - which is why it is recommended. It also provides you the flexibility of changing your view method names without having to change your templates. You can decide on a set of url names and hand them off to your designer to work on the templates, and you are free to name your view methods (or classes) the way you like.

Third, you need to pass the *full path* to the view **method** - so it needs to be `as_view` for class-based views and make sure you pass the correct number and type of arguments; and don't mix positional and keyword arguments.

Or, you can avoid most of the above by naming your URL patterns.

Comment: Good answer. The second point is particularly important as [it's one of Django's design philosophies (loose coupling)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/misc/design-philosophies/)

Comment: @burhan Thanks for the quick reply and specific answer. I've edited the question to include some code. Is this what you meant by using "as_view" in the url template tag? I'm sure i'm missing something stupid here but not sure what.

Comment: You need to give it the importable path (which means give it the app name as well).

As to your example on your [`urls.py`](https://gist.github.com/1877462), there is no code repetition there, except for the fact that you are typing '___view' a few times. You have exactly the name number of lines in both versions - four URL patterns.

Comment: @burhan =\ unfortunately giving the importable path did not work either. I modified the gist to show what i did. Is this what you intended?
side note: the urls.py example isn't to show how we are repeating lines, but content in the lines. we are adding the same syntax in each line and naming things which we may not have to name. I guess this comes down to preference.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see how this is violating the DRY principle - they are all separate views that do different things and they are each being given a unique identifier so as not to collide when being reversed. If anything, using named URLs will reduce the code you have to write at the template level and make your url scheme far more readable